# If Row 2 contains row 1 then copy row 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have large spreadsheet from where i want to retain only unique row value and remove the redundant data. This will give me unique combinations of rows using which i have to create DFD

**Input:**

```
R1 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

R2 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2

R3 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3

R4 1, 1, 1

R5 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1

R6 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3

R7 1, 2, 1

R8 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1

R9 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1
```

**OutPut:**

```
R3 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3

R6 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3

R8 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1

R9 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1
```

**Code:**

Code written is a waste.. it is just added up column values in array.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I want to remove the redundant rows which contains data which is already present in some other rows ( it can contains some extra data)

Comment: Please make clear in your post what your question is, and what your current code does, and where it needs improvement.

Comment: @Luuklag i have removed code as it was waste. i am not able to figure out How to solve this. please help.

Comment: Any progress Kish? What 'mad hatter' of a computer science prof gave you this?

Comment: is the commas represent different columns? or all are in a single column?

Comment: @KSSheon - The original code (before it was removed through an edit) seemed to indicate columns of digits, not digits concatenated into a single cell. That was my assumption while I worked on this.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting logic problem.

[image: recursive_dedupe1]
                 <sup>*before*</sup>

```
Sub recursive_RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long, sCI As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

            For cl = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1 Step 3
                Select Case (.Columns.Count - cl)
                    Case Is > 2
                        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(cl + 3), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                                    Key2:=.Columns(cl + 2), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                                    Key3:=.Columns(cl + 1), Order3:=xlDescending, _
                                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
                    Case Is > 1
                        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(cl + 2), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                                    Key2:=.Columns(cl + 1), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
                    Case Else
                        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(cl + 1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
                End Select
            Next cl

            For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                sCI = "COUNTIFS("
                For cl = 1 To .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    sCI = sCI & .Cells(1, cl).Resize(rw - 1, 1).Address(0, 0) & Chr(44) & _
                            .Cells(rw, cl).Value & Chr(44)
                Next cl
                sCI = Left(sCI, Len(sCI) - 1) & ")"
                If CBool(Application.Evaluate(sCI)) Then _
                    .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            Next rw

        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I had a problem for a while until I cheated with a native worksheet function.

[image: recursive_dedupe2]
                 <sup>*after*</sup>